# Force Unleashed - Vader just stands there

Tags: star-wars-the-force-unleashed

I'm finishing my play through of Force Unleashed, and I've gotten up to where you fight Vader on the Death Star. I battle him in the hallway, then he goes into the back room, with the hot floor. I fight him there for a little bit, and then he just ... stops. He doesn't attack, he doesn't defend, he doesn't throw things, he doesn't walk around, and I can't cause any damage to him.

Is this a known bug in FU? I know it was widely regarded to be an EXCEPTIONALLY buggy game. I'm playing the PC version on Steam.

Comment: Does this happen consistently? I would put this down to a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This does appear to be a bug, and it also occurs to some users on the [PS3 version](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/starwars2007/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-45553200&pid=933155). There hasn't been any sign of the developers acknowledging this one however.

It appears to occur after a certain time according to the linked gamespot thread, so maybe you could try defeat him faster. If that fails, it appears [some users](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/star-wars-force-unleashed-2/76345-vader-fight-freeze-me.html) have had luck reverting to an earlier save and starting that section of the game again.